# How to print string without space mark?

Tags: c

I tried to make a function that can split a string. (I need to create function that do the same like `strtok()`.)

I wrote something, but it only split the string one time and cant go forward to the next word in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * mystrtok(char *s, char delim)
{
    static char *p=NULL;
        if(s!=NULL) p=s;
    if(p==NULL) return NULL;
        char *tmp;
    tmp=p;
    while(1){
        if(*p=='\0'){
            break;
        }
        if(*p==delim){
            *p='\0';
            p++;
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return tmp;
}


int main()
{
    char s[] = "Let us split this string";
    // insert your code here:
    mystrtok(&s[0], ' ');
    printf("%s", s);
    mystrtok(NULL, ' ');
    printf("%s", s);
     mystrtok(NULL, ' ');
    printf("%s", s);
   
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

(Im trying to learn the basics so maybe I missed something stupid -_-)
TY all!!

Comment: You ignored the return value. That's what you should use to print. `char *tok = mystrtok(s, ' '); printf("%s", tok);`